# Compare two list and print number of times common elements apppear

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comparison

I would like to compare `items1` with `items2`, and print the most common numbers from `items2` that appear in `items1`.

Numbers in `items1` are fixed while numbers in `items2` are updated. I would also like to *count* the number of times each number appear. This is what I come up with so far:

```
import collections

items1 = [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 79, 014]
items2 = [528, 98, 925, 902, 67, 78, 89, 13, 24, 35, 46, 57]
results = collections.Counter()

for _ in items:
    number = (draws)
    results.update([tuple(number)])

print results.most_common(3)
```

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `random` library.

Comment: Where is `draws` and `items`
?

Comment: @Rinzler yep, the OP seems to be missing some code (`random` library was unused, `draws` and `items` don't exist etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
items1 = [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 79, 014]
items2 = [528, 98, 925, 902, 67, 78, 89, 13, 24, 35, 46, 57]
itemcount = {item: items2.count(item) for item in items1}

print [[number, itemcount[number]] for number in sorted(itemcount.keys(), key=lambda x:itemcount[x])[::-1][:5]] 
#Prints [common value: occurences], as such: [[89, 1], [46, 1], [35, 1], [24, 1], [13, 1]]
```